# not able to install elasticsearch-head plugin on my windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I have installed the latest zip files of ELK stack from thr official website elastic.co and extracted the folders. I am trying to install the elastic-search plugin by executing the below command

```
C:\ELK\elasticsearch-5.1.2\bin>elasticsearch-plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

but getting the below output

```
A tool for managing installed elasticsearch plugins

Commands
--------
list - Lists installed elasticsearch plugins
install - Install a plugin
remove - Removes a plugin from elasticsearch

Non-option arguments:
command

Option         Description
------         -----------
-h, --help     show help
-s, --silent   show minimal output
-v, --verbose  show verbose output
ERROR: Unknown plugin mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

can someone help me in installing this plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

That error message is not very descriptive, so i'm not sure if you have other problems but elasticsearch made a change in version 5, where they do no support site plugins

https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-site-plugins-with-elasticsearch-5-0

You can still use elasticsearch-head but you need to use a standalone server and something to manage cross domain security access like cors or a proxy

https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that the new Kibana version "kibana-5.1.2-windows-x86" has a new tab option called "Dev Tools", which provides a UI similar to marvel plug-in. I was just trying to have some plug-in to edit my queries, but this new version of kibana has a built-in feature.

Thanks